# Bind not supported on Opera mini?

Tags: javascript, opera

I see that function(){}.bind(this) is not supported in opera mini. Has anyone tried this?

The other option I have is to pass this as an argument. But only bind doesn't work is strange.

Comment: Not all browsers support `.bind()` right now, but you can always include a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility)  for it.

Comment: Got it, only ECMA 5th edition browsers support it. Thank you!